# How Can I share files in Microsoft Virtual Lab?

Tags: microsoft-virtualization

Have someone used Microsoft Virtual Labs?
Its remote desktop connection with Internet Explorer and you can make projects in Remote Computers Visual Studio 2010.
My question is how can I copy files to my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible as suggested by this answer here on [MSDN](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/CertGeneral/thread/dc2167e7-8ca6-4797-a425-424511127cd3)